# if(objValue instanceof Date) objValue store string its work or not?

Tags: java

```
Object objValue = null;
objValue = mapAcctProfParam.get(strKey).toString();
if(objValue instanceof Date){
     objValue = DateUtilities.stringFromDate(new Date(((Date)objValue).getTime()),
                                             "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
     debugLog(MODULE_NAME," going to DateUtilities"+objValue);  
}
```

if(objValue instanceof Date) is it always return false ,what is the solution for it.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `toString()` on the value from the map, which is always going to return a string... that's never going to be a `Date`. Try just changing this:

```
Object objValue = mapAcctProfParam.get(strKey);
```